# Python convert object value to int

Tags: python, object, math, instance

I've been using python for a while but I still run into elementary problems. 
I'm currently using exifread library in python to get latitude and longitude. I need to convert the DMS values to DD.

So far I have written the following:

```
    #!/bin/python
import math
import exifread
path_name = './IMAG0658.jpg'
f = open(path_name, 'rb')

tags = exifread.process_file(f)

GPSLat = tags['GPS GPSLatitude']
print tags['GPS GPSLatitudeRef']
print GPSLat.values[0]
print GPSLat.values[1]
print GPSLat.values[2]
GPSDDLat = GPSLat.values[0] + ((GPSLat.values[1] / 60) + (GPSLat.values[2]/3600))
print GPSDDLat
```

However it crashes after printing the following:

```
$python tempexif.py
N
33
52
433621/10000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tempexif.py", line 14, in <module>
    GPSDDLat = GPSLat.values[0] + ((GPSLat.values[1] / 60) + (GPSLat.values[2]/3600))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'instance' and 'int'
```

How do I do math against the list values rather than the object itself?

Comment: Sample image you can find [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/cameralabs/12382975864)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not complete since you do not provide the input file `IMAG0658.jpg`. But some things can still be said and we can still answer your question.

From your print statements it *looks* like `GPSLat.values[0]` and `GPSLat.values[1]` are both `int` values. But we see that `GPSLat.values[2]` looks like a fraction and thus is not an `int` value. From your error traceback we see that either `GPSLat.values[1]` or `GPSLat.values[2]` is actually an object instance. So at least one of those values prints like a numeric value but is actually an object instance.

The solution to your problem is to take those apparent numeric values, which are shown in `print` functions and thus are accessible by the `str` function as well, and convert them to numeric values before further computation. Since `GPSLat.values[2]` does not print like an int but does print like a fraction, we can use the `Fraction` type in the `fractions` module to do an easy conversion to `float`. So for each value, we use `str` to get the numeric-looking value then convert that to an actual numeric `float` value.

So we can do

```
from fractions import Fraction

GPSDDLat = ( float(str(GPSLat.values[0])) 
           + float(str(GPSLat.values[1])) / 60
           + float(Fraction(str(GPSLat.values[2]))) / 3600
           )
```

But without that file I cannot do an actual check of that code.

Comment: @EirNym: Are you sure? `Fraction` values should not cause that traceback since that kind of value can be used in the `/` operation.

Comment: the proposed solution worked. I'm don't understand why each one needed to be cast as a str then as a float rather than just casting as a float but it works. The last one being converted to a fraction then to float makes sense though... it's the casting as a string first that gets me.

Comment: Yes, I introspected objects and [source](https://github.com/ianare/exif-py/blob/ea5af101ff0a4c478cc05b1a193372d4b33218d8/exifread/utils.py#L87) speaks by itself. They modified it, unfortunately.

Comment: @StevenLutz: I do not know if each one *needs* all that work to become a `float` value. But I could see from your code and the printout that my technique would work and had no assurance that another one would also work.

Comment: I did try directly casting it as float prior to posting and it didn't work

Comment: "we know how to make standards better" (c) I wouldn't use this library if there's any better alternative. It's code a bit abandoned and some. I prefer libraries with better code, documentation, tests and some support.

Answer (score 0):

`GPSLat.values[x]` is an object (an instance, as it says in the Traceback).

In order to obtain the degree you need to do:

```
def val_2_deg(value):
    return float(value.num) / float(value.den)
```

and then change your formula to:

```
GPSDDLat = val_2_deg(GPSLat.values[0]) + val_2_deg(GPSLat.values[1])/60 + val_2_deg(GPSLat.values[2])/3600
```